# RDOSession GetSharedDefaultFolder throws 'Could not find the store DN'

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

Im trying to use GetActivitiesForTimeRange in RDOFolder2 for a specific Exchange User (not the currentUser)

```
RDOFolder2 folder = (RDOFolder2)CurrentUser.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder("example@example.com", rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
RDOItems items = folder.GetActivitiesForTimeRange(start.Date, end.Date, true);
```

But  `RDOSession.GetSharedDefaultFolder()`  throws this exception

> 'Could not find the store DN'

Is it possible to retrieve the FreeBusy Information without Credentials for a specific user using RDO?
Do we have to activate autodiscover?

is there a workaround with RDO? (we dont want to use EWS)
It works when I use RDOSession.GetDefaultFolder() (with authenticated User)

Answer (score 0):

If Redemption cannot retrieve the autodiscover XML for that mailbox, it would not be able to construct the store entry id (which includes the virtual server name unique to that mailbox).

If you already have the autodiscover XML for that mailbox, you can cache it first by calling `RDOSession.CacheAutodiscoverXML`

Comment: in which function does it construct the store entry id?
Unfortunately User.GetAutodiscoverXML() throws another error, so I cant cache it..



_"There are no autodiscover DNS records for this address"_

Comment: GetSharedDefaultFolder and GetSharedMailbox. What is the full error? Redemption combines errors from 4 or 5 different potential autodiscover sources into a single error.

Comment: Im Sorry, there you go : 
**Could not find the store DN
Could not retrieve autodiscover XML: GetAutodiscoverForEmailAddress: There are no autodiscover servers in the AD for this address
HTTP error 404 from https://www.XY.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
Server respose:**

Comment: That does no look like a full exception. Can you send an email to redemption (at) dimastr dot com? I will send you the debug version of Redemption.